# How to use await in angular lifecycle hooks?

Tags: angular, async-await, jspdf, angular-lifecycle-hooks

[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-final?file=app%2Fviews%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)

i am working on a angular application to export PDF but can't see the data values in exported PDF.
my approach:
i have 2 components (login,home) ,created a button(export) in login component and which will navigate the user to home component and afterViewInit it will generate the pdf.
i wrote the pdf generation code in ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook. when i try to await for the response it is not working.

i tried the following 2 ways   in `home.component.ts` but still nothing is working

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.fetchUserData().then(() => {
      this.generatepdf();
      this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
    });
  }


async ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    await this.fetchUserData();
    this.generatepdf();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('login');

}
```

is there a way we can await for the result and generate PDF ?

**Expected Result : awaited/fetched response should appear on generated PDF :)**

Answer (score 1):

Your pdf file is generated before the execution of change detection. Inject `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` to your constructor and call `this.cdr.detectChanges()` after you set `this.users`.

[Forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-final-sagtua?file=app/views/home/home.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the `async/await` pattern:

```
async ngAfterViewInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.fetchUserData();
    this.generatepdf();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('login');

}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-final-nwesmc?file=app%2Fviews%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

Comment: i tried async/await and .then both are not working.
you can fork the stackblitz and try , it is not working

Comment: Sorry forgot the Promise<void> return

Comment: your code is not woking as expected. did you open the downloaded pdf. pdf should display the number of users . that is the whole point for awaiting the response.  :)